# Can I split the array from text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have an array like this

```
["Member", "Friends", "Hello", "Components", "Family", "Lastname"]
```

and I need to split it at `"Components"` and get 2 arrays, which are

```
["Member", "Friends", "Hello"]
```

and

```
["Family", "Lastname"]
```

Can I do that and how?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array#slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000267):

```
class Array
  def msplit(m)
    idx = self.index(m)
    idx ? [self[0..idx-1], self[idx+1..-1]] : nil
  end
end

arr = ["Member", "Friends", "Hello", "Components", "Family", "Lastname"]
a, b = arr.msplit("Components")
a # => ["Member", "Friends", "Hello"]
b # => ["Family", "Lastname"]
a.msplit("Foo") # => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

In ruby 1.9 (because of [chunk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001523) method):

```
array = ["Member", "Friends", "Hello", "Components", "Family", "Lastname"]
a, b = array.chunk {|e| e != "Components"}.map {|a, b| b if a}.compact
p a, b #=> ["Member", "Friends", "Hello"] ["Family", "Lastname"]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be by

```
i = ary.index["Components"] - 1
ary[0..i]            #=>["Member", "Friends", "Hello"]
i = ary.index["Components"] + 1
ary[i..ary.length]   #=>["Family", "Lastname"]
```

or

```
ary[0..ary.index["Components"]-1]            #=>["Member", "Friends", "Hello"]
ary[ary.index["Components"]+1..ary.length]   #=>["Family", "Lastname"]
```

Also can use:

```
i = ary.index["Components"] - 1
ary.take(i)          #=>["Member", "Friends", "Hello"]
```

Comment: I got the error "undefined method '[]' for #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x3c86e9>"

Comment: Which class do you have? Array class or Enumerator class?

Answer (score 0):

```
newArray = oldArray.slice(5,2)
```

use the index and length methods to work out the 5 and 2 values

should leave you with:

newArray ["Family", "Lastname"]

oldArray ["Member", "Friends", "Hello"]

see the doc here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.3/classes/Array.html#M000398

Comment: assuming your initial array was called oldArray

Answer (score 0):

As an method:

```
class Array
  def split_by(val)
    [0, a.index(val)], a[a.index(val)+1..-1]
  end
end

array = ["Member", "Friends", "Hello", "Components", "Family", "Lastname"]
first, second = array.split_by("Complonents")
first
#=> ["Member", "Friends", "Hello"] 
second
#=> ["Family", "Lastname"]
```

or inliner

```
array = ["Member", "Friends", "Hello", "Components", "Family", "Lastname"]
first, second = array[0, a.index("Components")], a[a.index("Components")+1..-1]
```